# java socket Get IP of a conected Socket Client

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, serversocket

Hello Guys I'm currently trying some Socket,Socket Server application just to gain experience and knowledge.

And I have a small problem.

I Have tried all information on the internet to retrieve the IP Addresses of the connected Socket but I end up getting my Own Server IP address instead.

I Tried using `socketName.getRemoteSocketAddress(),socketName.getInetAddress();`

However both returned the server IP Address not the client IP Address.

My Code Looks like this.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
print("Server Established on port " + port);
Socket client = ss.accept();
print("Client connected , IP = " + client.getInetAddress() );
```

And when the client connects from a different Internet (My friend at home has the client app ran and tried to connect through typing my own public IP-PORT.

and yes I have made sure on my end that the Port is forwarded correctly and OPEN for connections , so far the app works great with everything running fine except that the IP Address I'm getting is the Server's IP not the Client IP.

Is there any way else to get it from server side , not from the client side.

Comment: Have you checked that your friend's public IP is not the same as yours? There are chances that you both are behind the same NAT.

Comment: @user3707125 Yeah My Friend public ip isn't the same as mine 

mine is like 41.xxx.xxx.xx his is 163.xxx.xxx.xxx whatever , but both methods return the server IP which is my IP ( The IP on which the server is running on ).

And What do you mean By NAT ? All I know is that I have opened port 4444 in my router so the client can connect (Port-Forwarding) will that do anything ?

Comment: This is the way. If those methods don't return it, the information isn't available, probably due to NAT somewhere or other. Possibly your own NAT.

Comment: @TheOnlyOne, You can read about NAT on wiki or somewhere else - just google it. And now using site like https://www.whatismyip.com/ verify that your real IPs are the ones you expect. After that we can investigate a bit further.